# Removing the Content Box from homepage

Tags: opencart2.x

On my Opencart website [www.nicotineeliquids.com.au](http://www.nicotineeliquids.com.au) I have a banner and there is a content box with it. I have a background image so I need the content box everywhere else except for my home page.

Is there a way I can remove this content box but keep the other content boxes in my products

Thanks

Comment: you will have to change in the tpl file.

Comment: What do I need to change I'm learning php

Comment: Please describe what you want to do in detail. I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks Ali. When you load my site the banner shows up. Behind the banner is a colored box I want to remove

Answer (score 0):

In your opencart installation locate

```
/catalog/view/theme/<your theme>/template/common/home.tpl
```

edit that file and remove the content box from the respective file so that it won't appear on your home page

Comment: Thanks @Rahul i opened up the home.tpl removed the content fom there but hit hasn't made a difference. Any thing else I might need to do

Comment: Are you using any vqmod for the template ?

Comment: Just the default opencart theme

Comment: I'm not sure how to add pictures here